# Why did Apple decide to lock my account and force me to change the password?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, icloud, password

A few days ago I got a message on my Mac that my Apple account was locked and I had to change my password. I did that, but ever since then, using Apple products has become a nightmare. I have Mac, iPhone, iPad and Apple TV, I'm signed in all of these devices and they are synced via iCloud.

All devices are asking for password multiple times a day, applications also synced via iCloud (for example Notability) can't sync because they detect iCloud not available. Multiple restart happened, I deleted local files, I deleted caches and still not working as it did a few days ago. Why on earth I have to enter multiple times my password on a device when I assume it should be enough (I assume an auth server should be able to serve all auth related requests centrally) only once?

Does Apple lock user accounts frequently and force users to change passwords? If not, then is possible to get some info why they did it in my case?

My account has had this password for a few months, or half a year. It is in use on daily basis for work.

Comment: How did you receive the notification. When you received it how did you go to the Apple site from it?

Comment: It was a pop-up window on Mac and the link on it opened iCloud page as far as I remember.

Comment: OK I suspect phishing. Whenever you are asked for a password change always go to the site by typing in the name of the site in the browser bar (or use Bing Google - well known search engines) never a direct link. So go to icloud.com and change your password - perhaps even close your browser and then restart it

Comment: Do you remember the exact wording of the popup, and did you check whether it really lead you to an Apple page? I would go to appleid.apple.com, log in there, change the password again and disable all application specific passwords (if there are any). Then log out and in again on all devices you have. If done, head over to appleid.apple.com and enable 2FA.

Comment: You were the victim of a phishing attack. I advise you to contact Apple directly about this problem and give them all the details about what happened to you.
Your AppleID password is now known from criminals, they changed it, and they use it. This is the reason why all your access are failing since this attack.

Answer (score 5):

You mentioned that "all devices are asking for password multiple times a day..."

Apple describes the type of message you could possibly receive in their support document [If your Apple ID is locked or disabled](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204106)

> If you or someone else enters your password, security questions, or
>   other account information incorrectly too many times, your Apple ID
>   automatically locks to protect your security and you can't sign in to
>   any Apple services. You can unlock your Apple ID after you verify your
>   identity.

If this was a legitimate security concern (which I believe it could very well be), you need to reset (change) your password and even enable two factor authentication.

Now, bear in mind that there are [AppleID phishing scams](http://appletechtalk.com/beware-apple-id-locked-scam/) that will tell you that you're account is locked and then provide you a link on which to confirm your account details.  If you clicked on this, you gave away your account info.  Reset it as soon as possible.

Note:  **Legitimate** firms (banks, Apple, Facebook, etc.) will never send you a link to validate or sign in.  Always go to their site(s) *manually*.

Comment: I wish all legitimate firms did do this but some don't.

Comment: AFAIK the text I got pop-up was "This Apple ID has been locked for security reasons". Since then I changed my password and logged out and logged back in to all devices.

Comment: @AndrasCsanyi So you did that... then what happened?  Did it finally resolve your problem?  Could you either select the accurate answer or write an answer that explains how you solve it? (StackExchange allows self-answers).  Then click the check mark next to the correct-for-you answer.